# Android Layout Cloning

Tags: android, layout, cloning

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/component1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/my_shape">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />   

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/component2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/my_shape"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />      

        </RelativeLayout>       

</RelativeLayout>
```

android:id="@+id/component2"
visibility is gone; which I want to attach in 
android:id="@+id/component1"
at runtime; not a single one but N-numbers of component 2 (changing property)

**All I mean to say, I want to make cloning of component2**

Can anyone please assist me with snip of code ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I am not sure to understand, why can't you use a `ListView` ?

Comment: @Sebastien; this is just a template. In my actual requirement i am having {TextView, EditText, 3 ImageButton} in Component 1 and {2 ImageButton, EditText} in component 2

Comment: Even with two different layouts for different rows, you still can use a ListView and use different ViewTypes in the ListAdapter.

Answer (score 2):

I thnik you are looking for re-using layout

you can create all your component in one layout and call that using `include` tag

```
<include layout="@layout/component"/>
<include layout="@layout/component"/>
<include layout="@layout/component"/>
```

[link here](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)

Comment: \@Fanos; sorry but i am not looking for reuse layout say, layout1.xml, layout2.xml,...layoutN.xml and use layout1.xml in 2,3,....N instead i want to reuse view inside in layout in Code using findViewById() but problem is that suppose i get view1 and view2 and make some changes in it but i think both are reference pointing to same object; in other word changes of one get reflected in another...that's why i am looking for cloning.

Answer (score 0):

Even with two different layouts for different rows, you still can use a ListView and use different ViewTypes in the ListAdapter.

An other way would be to have just a container layout in your layout xml (e.g. LinearLayout wrapped in a ScrollView) and add the components programmatically. You could have the layout for the component in a separate layout xml and in code, inflate that layout xml to a View (or ViewGroup), set the texts or whatever and finally add the component view to the container view.

I can provide code examples too, if one of the suggestions makes sense for you.

Comment: \@Ridcully; this is just a template. In my actual requirement i am having {TextView, EditText, 3 ImageButton} in Component 1 and {2 ImageButton, EditText} in component 2...it is possible with ListView

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve? In your example, component-1 is included in component-2. Is it that you want the component-1 part on top and a list of component-2 sections below that? Or do you wnat a list of component-1 sections and component-2 sections alternately or somehow mixed?